# How to decode string in specific charset and then encode it in UTF-8?

Tags: character-encoding, ada

How, in Ada, do I decode a string coming from the MS Windows terminal, then encode it in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in package `Ada.Strings.UTF_Encoding.Conversions` for UTF-handling.
As for retrieving text from the command-line you can use `Ada.Command_Line`, though there are also files/streams that you can use to get the standard input.